# Global signingConfig for multi-project build

Tags: android, gradle

I'm using project structure like this:

```
root
  |--build.gradle
  |--settings.gradle
  |
  |--child1
  |    |--build.gradle
  |
  |--child2
       |--build.gradle
```

In both child projects build.gradle contains the following:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

...

android {
    ...

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("release.keystore")
            storePassword "pass"
            keyAlias "alias"
            keyPassword "pass"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

How can I move signingConfigs part to the root project to reduce code duplication?

Answer (score 2):

I have try this code and it works. Be aware do not use signingConfigs in android-library project.

```
subprojects {

afterEvaluate {
    def isAndroidProject = project.plugins.hasPlugin('android')
    def isLibraryProject = project.plugins.hasPlugin('android-library')
    if (isAndroidProject || isLibraryProject) {
        android {
            compileSdkVersion 19
            buildToolsVersion 19.0.1

            compileOptions {
                sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
                targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            }

            if (isAndroidProject) {
                signingConfigs {
                    release {
                        storeFile file("${rootDir}/platform.keystore")
                        storePassword "android"
                        keyAlias "platform"
                        keyPassword "android"
                    }
                }

                buildTypes {
                    release {
                        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
                        minifyEnabled true
                        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), "${project.projectDir}/proguard-project.txt"
                    }
                }

                android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
                    variant.outputs.each  { output ->
                        def buildType = variant.buildType.name
                        if (buildType.equals('release')) {
                            def fileName = "${project.name}.apk";
                            output.outputFile = new File(output.outputFile.parent, fileName)

                            output.assemble.doLast {
                                copy {
                                    from output.outputFile.getAbsolutePath()
                                    into "../apks/"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Very similar to Alans answer but mine is accepted by Gradle. I didn't find any downsites yet:

In the root `build.gradle`:

```
import com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.SigningConfig

ext {
    mySigningConfigs = [
            release : SigningConfig.newInstance([
                    keyAlias     : 'release',
                    keyPassword  : 'keyPassword',
                    storeFile    : file('release.jks'),
                    storePassword: 'storePassword'
            ]),
            debug: SigningConfig.newInstance([
                    keyAlias     : 'debug',
                    keyPassword  : 'keyPassword',
                    storeFile    : file('debug.jks'),
                    storePassword: 'storePassword'
            ])]
}
```

`build.gradle` in submodules:

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig mySigningConfigs.release
        }

        debug {
            signingConfig mySigningConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could not find matching constructor for : com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.SigningConfig(LinkedHashMap)

Answer (score 1):

Given that all subprojects are Android projects, you could move the code into the [subprojects](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#subprojects%28groovy.lang.Closure%29)  configuration block defined in the root level build script.

```
subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'android'

    android { 
        ...
    }
}
```

If you need to you can also filter a list of project based on certain criteria and apply this configuration to them.

Comment: This doesn't work if some of your modules apply the 'android-library' plugin. you'd need to do subprojects { ... } after each module is evaluated

Comment: Any solutions for this?

Answer (score -1):

I realize this question is old, but for anyone else having the same issue I finally found this configuration which works for us:

In your root `build.gradle`:

```
ext {
    signingConfigs = {
        release {
            storeFile rootProject.file('keystores/release.keystore')
            storePassword 'pass'
            keyAlias 'alias'
            keyPassword 'pass'
        }

        // Optionally other configs like 'debug' here...
    }

    // Other ext properties here... 
}
```

Then in individual module `build.gradle` files (except library modules):

```
android {
    // ...

    signingConfigs rootProject.ext.signingConfigs
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        // ...
    }
}
```

This way at least you don't have to duplicate the password/store name everywhere. It also makes it simpler to [switch to using environment variables](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#release-mode) for the passwords which is a good practice.

Comment: Does not work. I tried it and get "No signature of method..."